# Displaying gif animations

Tags: jquery

I have this code to load a gif but I don't understand the `$(".block1").load("views/changepass.template.php");` part. Please explain.

```
$(function() {
    $(".changepass").click(function() {
        $(".block1").load("views/changepass.template.php");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/ should provide all the information you need about the `.load()` method

Answer (score 0):

Here's an annotated version of the script, which should explain everything :

```
$(function() {//When the document is ready to be interacted with, ...
    $(".changepass").click(function() {//establish a 'click' event handler for .changepass element(s), which ...
        $(".block1").load("views/changepass.template.php");//loads content from the server into .block1 element(s), then ...
        return false;//ensures the natural 'click' action of the clicked element is not executed.
    });
});
```